# Failable initializer for convenience init fails

Tags: ios, swift, initialization, extension-methods, failable

I have the following `NSDate` extension initializer to create a `NSDate` object from a given string.

```
extension NSDate {
    convenience init(string: String) {
        let dateStringFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateStringFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
        let date = dateStringFormatter.dateFromString(string)

        self.init(timeInterval:0, sinceDate:date!)
    }
}
```

But the call to `self.init` method force unwraps the `date` variable which is not safe. So I'm trying to make this a failable initializer.

```
extension NSDate {
    convenience init?(string: String) {
        let dateStringFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateStringFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"

        guard let date = dateStringFormatter.dateFromString(string) else {
            return nil
        }

        self.init(timeInterval:0, sinceDate:date)
    }
}
```

But it crashes with a *EXC_BAD_ACCESS* error at the `nil` returning line. I can't figure out why.

What am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: I know this is crazy, but add a pointless `self.init` call inside the guard (doesn't matter what, as long as it succeeds). I've had compiler errors for not fully initing self even if I return nil.

Comment: @LouFranco Whoa, that worked! Is this a Swift bug or are we supposed to do this?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem in the iOS Simulator, your code works fine for me.

Comment: @MartinR I was running this code on a device. I'm using Xcode 7.3.

Comment: Strange, works on my iOS 9 device as well.

Comment: I do not trust 7.3 at all.  I would either go to 7.3.1 or backwards.

Answer (score -1):

If you use `extension` you need to initialize the "superclass" before returning nil. See

```
convenience init?(string: String) {
    let dateStringFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateStringFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"

    guard let date = dateStringFormatter.dateFromString(string) else {
        self.init()
        return nil
    }

    self.init(timeInterval:0, sinceDate:date)
}
```

The [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html) states

> All of a class’s stored properties—including any properties the class inherits from its superclass—must be assigned an initial value during initialization.

Comment: That changed with Swift 2.2/Xcode 7.3. From https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/RN-Xcode-Archive/Chapters/xc7_release_notes.html: Inside a class, a designated initializer that is either failable (init?()) or throwing (init() throws) is allowed to exit before initializing all stored properties and calling super.init(). This behavior makes designated initializers more consistent with convenience initializers. **Convenience initializers can also fail before performing a self.init() delegation.**

Comment: And otherwise the code should not compile, and not crash with a runtime exception.

Comment: @MartinR I don't think that applies to `extension/inheritance`.

Comment: If the code does not satisfy the requirements for initialization then it does not compile (but OP's code compiles).